# Change hibernate.cfg.xml runtime - first part

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I have a file defined 'hibernate.cfg.xml' empty:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools. -->
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>       


    <mapping resource="...

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

so as to allow the user to enter, the first interaction, the credentials of the DB:

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {


private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
private static String configFile = CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION;

static {
    try {
        configuration.configure(configFile);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private HibernateSessionFactory() {
}

...

public static void setProperties(String urlDB, String username,
        String password) {

    try{
        configuration=new AnnotationConfiguration();
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", urlDB);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password );  

    HibernateSessionFactory.sessionFactory=configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

But when I try to launch the connection with the DB, the app always refers to the empty configuration file:

```
    10:27:52,771  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:109 - connection properties: {user=, password=****}
    10:27:52,771  WARN SettingsFactory:133 - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at com.appDial.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.setProperties(HibernateSessionFactory.java:138)
        at com.appDial.service.DatabaseSet.controlParam(DatabaseSet.java:45)
        at com.appDial.service.DatabaseSet.setDatabase(DatabaseSet.java:24)
        at com.appDial.controller.BaseController.setDB(BaseController.java:346)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Can you tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: please post the second part (`UnsupportedOperationException` thing) as new question; as you have made progress on config part. Doing so will save time / analysis of people visiting this page for similar problems. Thnx.

Comment: I did :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998563/change-hibernate-cfg-xml-runtime-second-part

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this property

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
```

with

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
```

Comment: Thanks to the indication

Answer (score 1):

You are first configuring Hibernate via xml in static block `configuration.configure(configFile)` and then again in `setProperties` method via `configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration()` *[however invocation of this is not evident from code you posted]*

In case of these mixed configuration i.e. xml and annotation; xml configuration takes precedence. Thus removing the xml configuration for *url*, *username* and *password* should help.
Also correct the dialect as pointed out in another answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

I have made progress, but now I get another error reported, I'm trying to figure out what is due to:

   `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection`

Comment: Glad to help!! Kindly accept the answer for benefit of others :) Thnx.