# Change hibernate.cfg.xml runtime - second part

Tags: java, spring, hibernate.cfg.xml

I'm trying to use a mixed form for the definition of the SessionFactory, because I want to allow the user using my webapp (SpringMVC +hibernate), the first interaction, define the credentials to access the database.

I defined the following files:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>        

     <mapping resource="com/appDial/hibernateGenerate/Eventlog.hbm.xml" />
    ....
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateSessionFactory.java

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
private static String configFile = CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION;

static {
    try {
        configuration.configure(configFile);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private HibernateSessionFactory() {
}

/**
 * Returns the ThreadLocal Session instance.  Lazy initialize
 * the <code>SessionFactory</code> if needed.
 *
 *  @return Session
 *  @throws HibernateException
 */
public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            rebuildSessionFactory();
        }
        session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession()
                : null;
        threadLocal.set(session);
    }

    return session;
}

/**
 *  Rebuild hibernate session factory
 *
 */
public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        configuration.configure(configFile);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 *  Close the single hibernate session instance.
 *
 *  @throws HibernateException
 */
public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
    threadLocal.set(null);

    if (session != null) {
        session.close();
    }
}

/**
 *  return session factory
 *
 */
public static org.hibernate.SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 *  return session factory
 *
 *  session factory will be rebuilded in the next call
 */
public static void setConfigFile(String configFile) {
    HibernateSessionFactory.configFile = configFile;
    sessionFactory = null;
}
/**
 *  return hibernate configuration
 *
 */
public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
    return configuration;
}

public static void setProperties(String urlDB, String username,
        String password) {


    try{
        HibernateSessionFactory.configuration=new AnnotationConfiguration();

        HibernateSessionFactory.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", urlDB);
        HibernateSessionFactory.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        HibernateSessionFactory.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password );  

        HibernateSessionFactory.configuration.configure();

        HibernateSessionFactory.sessionFactory=HibernateSessionFactory.configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
.....
 <tx:annotation-driven/>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
</bean>
......
```

After entering the database credentials seems that the initialization of the SessionFactory to be successful,but just try to interact with a DAO object I get this error:

```
 15:57:22,344 ERROR RegistroDAO:117 - find all failed
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
        at       org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1577)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
        at com.appDial.hibernateGenerate.RegistroDAO.findAll(RegistroDAO.java:115)
        at com.appDial.persistence.PersistenceRegister.getRegisters(PersistenceRegister.java:40)
        at com.appDial.persistence.PersistenceRegister$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f6d1bc49.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:618)
        at com.appDial.persistence.PersistenceRegister$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7a434138.getRegisters(<generated>)
        at com.appDial.controller.BaseController.printHello(BaseController.java:178)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My doubt is that it is due to the TransactionManager that is initialized during deployment, but with a SessionFactory without credentials.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16519370/1910582)

Comment: Good morning,
I checked the various points and compared.
The only problem that I use version 3.1 of hibernate and I can not recall the code: `new ServiceRegistryBuilder (). ApplySettings (configuration.getProperties ()). BuildServiceRegistry ()`

Comment: GM, its for Hibernate 4.x

Comment: I did some tests and I was able to work around the problem by initializing in the class DAO, hibernate template
`setHibernateTemplate (new HibernateTemplate (HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory ()));`

and this has caused some in the declaration of the bean in applicationContext.xml:

`<bean id =" RegistroDAO "class =" com.appDial.hibernateGenerate.RegistroDAO ">
<property name = "sessionFactory">
<ref bean = "sessionFactory" />
</ property>
</ bean> `

Now the problem becomes how to redefine the session factory object for each bean